# Google Sheets Service Account "keyfilePath error" NodeJs

Tags: node.js, json, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to create a script to access data from a Google Sheet using a service account for authentication. However, when I run the script, I encounter an error that I'm having trouble understanding:
**Error: Cannot find module './key.json'**

This situation seems unusual to me because I'm confident that the service account JSON file's path is correct. My file hierarchy is as follows:
[File Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCDcA.png)

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { authenticate } = require("@google-cloud/local-auth");

const spreadsheetId = "1ZxZ0kghl5GueyQgTVMILyfsHVFgXPMZT6_qlt1oPBZA";
const range = "Sheet1!A1:D10";

// Create a Google Sheets client
const sheets = google.sheets({
  version: "v4",
});

// Authenticate the client
authenticate({
  keyfilePath: "./key.json",
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
}).then((credentials) => {
  sheets.auth = credentials;

  // Get the data from the Google Sheets doc
  sheets.spreadsheets.values
    .get({
      spreadsheetId,
      range,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.data.values;

      // Print the data
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I attempted to re-download the Service Account JSON file in case it was corrupted, but the error persists.